# bst file not producing page ranges

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I have a rather limited understanding of `bst`'s postfix syntax, and am hoping that someone with more knowledge of the system could kindly point out the source of a problem I am experiencing from a `.bst` file provided by a journal. Use of this particular bibliographic style file results in failure to print page ranges for most `@article` entries in my `.bib` file. I am using `pdflatex` and `bibtex`.

The relevant snippet from the `.bst` file for articles and the formatting of their volume/page numbers is as follows:

```
FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" } 
    'skip$
  if$  
}

FUNCTION {bolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" } 
    { "{\bf " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$  
}

FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "pp." }

FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
        { bbl.pages pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
        { bbl.page pages tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {first.page}
{ 't :=
  ""
    {  t empty$ not t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = not and }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ *
      t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        {
          ", " *
          pages first.page *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  bolden
  format.journal.pages
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { journal
      emphasize
      "journal" output.check
      add.blank
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

As can be seen, the `article` function calls `format.vol.num.pages`, which is tasked with inserting the volume and number of pages. After adding and emboldening the volume, `format.journal.pages` is called. In this function, the `pages` field from the `@article` bibliographic entry gets added to the stack. Provided that it is non-empty, then it is duplicated and another check for emptiness is made. I do not understand the purpose of duplicating and checking emptiness after having already established non-emptiness. If it is empty after duplication, then the page range is printed (this is the path I want); otherwise, only the first page is printed, which is the route that almost always seems to be taken. If I use `{ pop$ format.pages }` for both true/false routes of the `if` statement, then the full page range is printed, but in this case the volume is dropped (perhaps because it was popped prematurely off the stack).

I have also removed the "pp" added by `bbl.pages` by rewriting is as follows:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "" }
```

However, I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to remove the "pp". Deleting `bbl.pages` from `format.pages` again upsets the stack.

---

Here is an MWE together with its output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scicite}

\begin{document}

According to the theory of special relativity~\cite{einstein1905}, \ldots

\bibliography{a}
\bibliographystyle{Science}

\end{document}
```

Bib file (a.bib):

```
@article{einstein1905,
  title={Zur elektrodynamik bewegter k{\"o}rper},
  author={Einstein, Albert},
  journal={Annalen der physik},
  volume={322},
  number={10},
  pages={891--921},
  year={1905},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

[image]

The full `bst` file can be accessed [here](http://www.sciencemag.org/site/feature/contribinfo/prep/TeX_help/Science.bst).

The `scicite` style file can be accessed [here](http://www.sciencemag.org/site/feature/contribinfo/prep/TeX_help/scicite.sty).

Comment: Would it be possible to link to the full `.bst` file (and add a short example document with a relevant citation). I always need to actually see the `.bst` working to understand what is going on.

Comment: For removing the "pp." your method seems the quickest and requires the fewest changes to the code. If I'm guessing correctly (and I have to guess, since I can't see all definitions) an alternative would be to replace the entire `pages multi.page.check
        { bbl.pages pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
        { bbl.page pages tie.or.space.connect }
      if$` block with just `pages n.dashify`.

Comment: @moewe: Hi moewe. Thanks a lot for your help. I've added a URL for the `bst` file to the question and will prepare a short example forthwith.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy things first. Yes, setting

```
FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "" }
```

and

```
FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "" }
```

is probably the cheapest way to get rid of the "p."/"pp." in the bibliography.

It might be slightly nicer, though, to just replace the entire function `format.pages` with the simpler.

```
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages n.dashify }
  if$
}
```

Note that both approaches will remove the "p."/"pp." for all entry types and not just for `@article`s. This may or may not be desired.

---

Now to your question about `format.journal.pages`. The function is called in `format.vol.num.pages`. At that point the previous functions have already pushed quite a few things onto the stack. In particular the stack will contain

- the formatted volume: `{\bf 322}` and
- the formatted journal (with a trailing space) `{\it Annalen der Physik/}`

In comes `format.journal.pages` and tests for emptiness of the `pages` field. Since nothing exciting happens if the field is empty, let us assume it is non-empty. If the field is non-empty the function calls `duplicate$`, which pops the top literate from the stack (`{\bf 322}`) and pushed two copies of it. The stack now contains

- a copy of the formatted volume `{\bf 332}`
- the formatted volume: `{\bf 322}` and
- the formatted journal (with a trailing space) `{\it Annalen der Physik/}`

`empty$` now pops the top literal (the copy of the volume) and checks it for emptiness. Once we are in the `if$` the stack contains the two items from before.

- the formatted volume: `{\bf 322}` and
- the formatted journal (with a trailing space) `{\it Annalen der Physik/}`

If the popped and tested literal was empty (which means there was no `volume` field) the function `pop$`s the next literal from the stack (which is also empty) and proceeds to format the pages field as normal. If the tested literal was not empty, the function adds `,` to the end of the first literal on the stack (which is the original of the copy we just tested for emptiness and contains the volume number), formats the `pages` field with `first.page` and then concatenates the resulting two literals on the stack (so that you get the `<formatted volume>, <formatted pages>`).

The `duplicate$ empty$` thus branches on whether or not there was a `volume` field in the entry: Try it out, you'll find that the full page range is printed if there is no `volume`, but that only the first page is printed if there is a `volume`. It does not test the `pages` field.

If you want to see the full page range in all cases, you could try

```
FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        {
          ", " *
          format.pages *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

It does not look much simpler than the previous code, but we now call `format.pages` in both branches. The structure of the file makes it quite tricky to simplify/unify this `if$` further, though.

Comment: That's a really fine explanation. I appreciate you walking through the stack mechanics. It has given me a much better grasp of what is occurring. Also your solution for adding a page range regardless of the presence of a volume worked perfectly. PS: What does the asterisk (*) signify in the format.journal.pages function?

Comment: @user001 Sorry, I only just saw your PS. The `*` pops the top two literals from the stack, concatenates the two and then pushes the result back onto the stack. So `", " *` comes down to: "Add `, ` to the end of the last string on the stack." Similarly `format.pages *` adds the formatted pages to the end of the last literal on the stack.

Comment: No problem, and thanks again for the tremendously helpful explanations.