# removing a comma after a field in a bst file

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

Apropos to my [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/483134/10127) on `bst` file editing (and using the same `bst` file described there), I tried to add a title to the bibliographic output with a period at the end. This apparently worked well but for a pesky comma that is appended after the period following the title. I cannot figure out where this comma is coming from or how to remove it. Perhaps it is a general delimiter added after each field. What would be the simplest way to remove it?

I appended a period to the end of the title by adding `". " *` to format.title:

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" } 
    { title ". " * "t" change.case$
      % title "t" change.case$       % original line
    }    
  if$  
}
```

I then added a title to articles by adding the line `format.title "title" output.check` to `FUNCTION {article}`:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.title "title" output.check      % added this line
      journal
      emphasize
      "journal" output.check
      add.blank
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

The MWE is as before, but the output has changed (showing the undesired comma after the title).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scicite}

\begin{document}

According to the theory of special relativity~\cite{einstein1905}, \ldots

\bibliography{a}
\bibliographystyle{Science}

\end{document}
```

Bib file (a.bib):

```
@article{einstein1905,
  title={Zur elektrodynamik bewegter k{\"o}rper},
  author={Einstein, Albert},
  journal={Annalen der physik},
  volume={322},
  number={10},
  pages={891--921},
  year={1905},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

[image]

The full `bst` file can be accessed [here](http://www.sciencemag.org/site/feature/contribinfo/prep/TeX_help/Science.bst).

The `scicite` style file can be accessed [here](http://www.sciencemag.org/site/feature/contribinfo/prep/TeX_help/scicite.sty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not modify the `format.title` macro to bring its own punctuation. Instead you can tell BibTeX to start a new sentence after the title with

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.title "title" output.check
      new.sentence
      journal
      emphasize
      "journal" output.check
      add.blank
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein1905,
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}},
  author  = {Einstein, Albert},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

According to the theory of special relativity~\cite{einstein1905}, \ldots

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{Science-user001}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: A. Einstein, Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper. Annalen der Physik 322, 891 (1905).]

Note the corrected capitalisation in the `title` and `journal` fields. Note also the double curly braces around the `title` field. They suppress the sentence casing function that would otherwise apply English sentence case rules to the German title (which would result in orthographically incorrect output). Usually I am *strongly* opposed to protecting the entire `title` field with double curly braces. I believe it is much better to protect only those words that need case protection separately from the sentence casing mechanism. See [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864). But this is an exception to the rule I feel.

Comment: The number of modifications you want to apply to `Science.bst` make me think that it might be cleaner to start from a different style altogether. The `makebst` offers has a way to produce customised bibliography style for you. And there are a lot of other ready-made styles available.

Comment: Thanks again for imparting your knowledge on this subject. I am most grateful. I did take advantage of the `*` from our previous discussion, but you have thoughtfully pointed out a better approach. I'm hoping that's the last modification I will require. Unfortunately, that style file is what the journal provides; evidently they receive very few latex submissions, and their style file has consequently not been updated to reflect the current bibliographic practices of the journal.

Comment: @user001 If it is their style I would stick with it for now. If you are worried the style does not produce the correct output I would urge you to contact the editor and inform them about the discrepancy between the expected and actual output.